# Javascript disabled when i load this file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem in my Symfony2.4 project .i have 2 selects and 2 radiobuttons 
i want to disable the first  and make second  enabled on each click here is my code

```
<div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 ui-sortable">
                        <span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="mensuelle" checked="checked"style="opacity: 1!important;" /> Mensuelle   
                        </span>
                        </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7 ui-sortable">
                        <span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="trimestre"style="opacity: 1!important;" /> Trimestre    
                        </span>
                        </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 ui-sortable">
                        <span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

                        <select id="mois" name="mois" class="form-control" size="1">
                          <option value="Janvier">Janvier</option>
                          <option value="Fevrier">Fevrier</option>
                          <option value="Mars">Mars</option>
                          <option value="Avril">Avril</option>
                          <option value="Mai">Mai</option>
                          <option value="Juin">Juin</option>
                          <option value="Juillet">Juillet</option>
                          <option value="Aout">Aout</option>
                          <option value="Septembre">Septembre</option>
                          <option value="Octobre">Octobre</option>
                          <option value="Novembre">Novembre</option>
                          <option value="Decembre">Decembre</option>
                        </select>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 ui-sortable">
                          <span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                          <select id="trimest" name="trimest" class="form-control" size="1">    
                            <option value="1er Trimestre">1er Trimestre</option>
                           <option value="2eme Trimestre">2eme Trimestre</option>
                           <option value="3eme Trimestre">3eme Trimestre</option>
                           <option value="4eme Trimestre">4eme Trimestre</option>
                         </select>    

                          </span>
                        </div>
```

and this is the script :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


                     document.getElementById('trimest').disabled=true;

                    $('input:radio[name="group1"]').change(function() {
                      if ($(this).val() === 'mensuelle') {
                        // append stuff
                        document.getElementById('trimest').disabled=true;
                        document.getElementById('mois').disabled=false;

                      }
                      else {
                        document.getElementById('trimest').disabled=false;
                        document.getElementById('mois').disabled=true;
                      }
                    });


   </script>
```

i have no problems here but when i include this file file in my page the script don't works

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9iqIn8LtQ7gdmdZYmlhYVM1alE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you sure you are running your JS code after the DOM is ready?

Comment: Yes i told that i have no problem if i remove the file forms.js but the probelm when i include the file

Comment: You are not mentioning any "form.js" anywhere in your question...

Comment: here is the forms.js https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9iqIn8LtQ7gdmdZYmlhYVM1alE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the JS Code is executed before the DOM is completely setup.

Try the follwing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Your Code
 });
```

When you use that, your script will be executed, after the DOM is setup, and all the inputs etc. can be accessed by jQuery

See http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ (good idea @sebnukem)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that JQuery *has been properly loaded*.

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." Make sure the JS code is running once the DOM is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { // add this
  document.getElementById('trimest').disabled=true;

  $('input:radio[name="group1"]').change(function() {
    console.log('radio button clicked'); // do you see this?
    if ($(this).val() === 'mensuelle') {
      // append stuff
      document.getElementById('trimest').disabled=true;
      document.getElementById('mois').disabled=false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('trimest').disabled=false;
      document.getElementById('mois').disabled=true;
    }
  });
); // and this
</script>
```

See http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

What does your console say?

Comment: the same problem :'( i don't know what to do ?

Comment: Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi)
 Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi)